# Use a field in where clause without select it

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

I am trying to use a field in a where clause without selecting it

something like SELECT field 1 FROM table WHERE field2 = 'foo'

```
$where= $onlyissuing ? " WHERE ISSUE = 1" : "";
$sql="
SELECT c.*
     , d.Name_fr as DEVISE 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT a.Currency_ISO3 as value
            , a.Rank as ISSUE
            , b.Name_fr as PAYS 
         FROM countries_currencies a
            , countrylist b
        where a.Country_ISO3 = b.Country_ISO3
     ) c
     , currencylist d 
 where c.value = d.Currency_ISO3
 ";
$sql='
SELECT e.*
     , CONCAT(e.value, " - ", e.PAYS, " - ", e.DEVISE ) AS label 
  FROM ('.$sql.')e
  ';
 $sql = $sql.$where;
```

As such it works but if I don't select the a.Rank as issue, I get an error
    Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ISSUE' in 'where clause'

Thanks to the comments, working solution:

```
$sql='SELECT a.Currency_ISO3 as value, b.Name_fr as PAYS, c.Name_fr as DEVISE, CONCAT(a.Currency_ISO3, " - ", b.Name_fr, " - ", c.Name_fr ) AS label FROM countries_currencies a INNER JOIN countrylist b on a.Country_ISO3=b.Country_ISO3 INNER JOIN currencylist c on a.Currency_ISO3=c.Currency_ISO3 WHERE a.Rank=1';
```

Comment: (1) Using standard explicit JOIN syntax will make your queries much easier to read and maintain, (2) An outer query can only see the fields a subquery SELECTs, it cannot "peek" inside; (3) It's not clear why you are even using a subquery when it looks like you should just be able to join through.

Comment: To put it another way, trying to access the fields a subquery does not SELECT from outside that subquery is like trying to access the local variables of a method call from the code calling the method in a conventional programming language.

Comment: You need to give more details about what you are trying to do and why. Provide the expected result. Your query is very confusing and could definitely be simplified.

Comment: Or like trying to rearrange the sails on a ship in a bottle.. from inside a different bottle

Comment: Just thoughts about the text layout. We spend all our lives reading text with punctuation rules and you make it different so we have to stop and read every word and line of text? And the parser doesn't care. Make your code easy to read for people. The computer really doesn't care. People will spend a lot of time reading your code. Make it easy to understand for them? Imagine you have to read a few pages of science text laid out using your rules? It is not helpful to people? Right? Please tell me your were not taught to do this in any official course. Peace.

Comment: To add to Ryan's comment, I inherited a project where the previous dev decided it would be a good idea to store the WHEREs for a lot of queries in separate string variables like this question does. They tended to be set about three pages of code before the few queries (sometimes only one) that used them. Needless to say I hate having to go into that project, my opinion of that dev dropped significantly.

Comment: Thanks for the comments about simplifying and more specifically on the outside/inside problem. That helped me to understand the issue and come out with a working solution

Comment: Also, choose aliases sensibly...  you use: `countries_currencies a`. Why make people work harder to translate aliases to the table? Would 'cc' be so bad? Ok, two characters to type but at least easier to remember when reading the code? Spot the issue with: `countrylist b`. May I suggest that you write your code with decent layout (indentation) and aliases. And I suspect you will find the issues with the code for yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comments, the only fields you can access from outside a subquery are the fields it SELECTs. That said, I don't really think this query needs to have any subqueries. *My PHP is a bit weak, so double check the string concatenation.*

```
sql = "
SELECT cc.Currency_ISO3 AS value
   , cc.Rank AS ISSUE
   , coL.Name_fr AS PAYS
   , cuL.Name_fr AS DEVISE
   , CONCAT(cc.Currency_ISO, ' - ', coL.Name_fr, ' - ', cuL.Name_fr) AS label
FROM countries_currencies AS cc
INNER JOIN countrylist AS coL ON cc.Country_ISO3 = coL.Country_ISO3
INNER JOIN currencylist AS cuL ON cc.Currency_ISO3 = cuL.Currency_ISO3
".($onlyissuing ? "WHERE cc.Rank = 1" : "")
;
```

You'll note that since there is no subquery, `Rank` can be referenced directly in the `WHERE`, so it does not need included in the `SELECT` (and even if it were, you could not use an alias from that `SELECT` in that `WHERE`.)

Comment: Thanks, I had succeeded in getting a working solution, where Rank is not selected. But since I did it following your advice, I think it's fair to give you credit for your answer, which nicely includes the $onlyissuing parameter